# Why JSON data shows "undefined" in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, json, scripting

Hey am trying to show some quotes using my JSON file. But it shows undefined. Can anyone check the below html and JavaScript.

***My Javascript***

```
const resultEl = document.querySelector('.allquotes');
const pageSize = document.querySelector('select[name="page-size"]');
const pageCurr = document.querySelector('input[name="page-curr"]')
const resultCount = document.querySelector('.result-count')
const pageNoCurr = document.querySelector('.page-no-curr');
const pageNoCount = document.querySelector('.page-no-count')
const btnFirst = document.querySelector('.page-btn-first');
const btnPrev = document.querySelector('.page-btn-prev');
const btnNext = document.querySelector('.page-btn-next');
const btnLast = document.querySelector('.page-btn-last');

let results = [];

const getResultCount = () => results.length;
const getPageSize = () => +pageSize.value;
const getCurrPage = () => +pageCurr.value;
const getPageCount = () => Math.ceil(getResultCount() / getPageSize());

const pageResponse = (records, pageSize, page) =>
  (start => records.slice(start, Math.min(records.length, start + pageSize)))
  (pageSize * (page - 1));

const main = async() => {
  btnFirst.addEventListener('click', navFirst);
  btnPrev.addEventListener('click', navPrev);
  btnNext.addEventListener('click', navNext);
  btnLast.addEventListener('click', navLast);
  pageSize.addEventListener('change', changeCount);

  results = await retrieveAllQuotes();
  updatePager(results);
  redraw();
};
const redraw = () => {
  resultEl.innerHTML = '';
  const paged = pageResponse(results, getPageSize(), getCurrPage());
  const contents = document.createElement('div');
  contents.innerHTML = paged.map(record => `<div class='latestatus'><p class='copytxt'>${record.quotes}</p><div> <button class="copystatus btn">Copy</button></div></div>`).join('');
  resultEl.append(contents);
};

const navFirst = (e) => {
  pageNoCurr.textContent = 1;
  pageCurr.value = 1;
  redraw();
}

const navPrev = (e) => {
  const pages = getPageCount();
  const curr = getCurrPage();
  const prevPage = curr > 1 ? curr - 1 : curr;
  pageCurr.value = prevPage;
  pageNoCurr.textContent = prevPage;
  redraw();
}

const navNext = (e) => {
  const pages = getPageCount();
  const curr = getCurrPage();
  const nextPage = curr < pages ? curr + 1 : curr;
  pageCurr.value = nextPage;
  pageNoCurr.textContent = nextPage;
  redraw();
}

const navLast = (e) => {
  pageNoCurr.textContent = getPageCount();
  pageCurr.value = getPageCount();
  redraw();
}

const changeCount = () => {
  updatePager();
  redraw();
};

const updatePager = () => {
  const count = getPageCount();
  const curr = getCurrPage();
  pageCurr.value = curr > count ? 1 : curr;
  pageNoCurr.textContent = curr > count ? 1 : curr;
  pageNoCount.textContent = count;
  resultCount.textContent = getResultCount();
};

const retrieveAllQuotes = async function() {
  // here we are making a network call to your api
  const response = await fetch('/stat.json');
  
  // then converting it to json instead of a readable stream
  const data = await response.json();

  // finally go over the array and return new object with renamed key
  const results = data.map(val => ({quotes: val.status}));

  return results;
}

main();
```

***My Html***

```
<div class="allquotes"></div>
<div class="pagable-status">
  <label>Page <span class="page-no-curr">1</span> of <span class="page-no-count">1</span></label>
  <div class="pagable-actions">
    <button class="page-btn-first">&#x226A;</button>
    <button class="page-btn-prev">&#60;</button>
    <input type="number" name="page-curr" min="1" value="1" />
    <button class="page-btn-next">&#62;</button>
    <button class="page-btn-last">&#x226B;</button>
    <select name="page-size">
      <option>5</option>
      <option>10</option>
      <option>20</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <label>(<span class="result-count"></span> items)</label>
</div>
```

I said that I use a JSON file. You can notice it on the javascript. There is a file name called ***stat.json***.
Location in my javascript

```
const retrieveAllQuotes = async function() {
  // here we are making a network call to your api
  const response = await fetch('/stat.json');
```

The content of stat.json is

```
[
    {
        "quotes":"Do what is right not what is easy."
    },
    {
        "quotes":"Hey there, Whatsapp is using me."
    },
    {
        "quotes":"Too Busy"
    },
    {
        "quotes":"Only you can give me that feeling."
    },
    {
        "quotes":"I had a horribly busy day in converting oxygen into carbon dioxide"
    },
    {
        "quotes":"Be yourself; everyone else is already taken"
    },
    {
        "quotes":"Your attitude may hurt me, But main can Kill You!!"
    },
    {
        "quotes":"Love is Blind, be careful."
    },
    {
        "quotes":"'SUCCESS' is depend on U."
    },
    {
        "quotes":"If you love someone set it free."
    },
    {
        "quotes":"Love is sweet, When it's new. But it is sweeter when it's true."
    },
    {
        "quotes":"Where ther is love, there is life."
    },
    {
        "quotes":"Not always 'Available' try your luck.."
    },
    {
        "quotes":"I am not changed it's just I grew up and you should try too."
    },
    {
        "quotes":"The biggest slap to your enimies is your success."
    },
    {
        "quotes":"Born to express, not to impress."
    },
    {
        "quotes":"When nothing goes right! go left."
    },
    {
        "quotes":"I allow myself to be badass confident in all that I do."
    },
    {
        "quotes":"Sometimes you succeed and other time you learn."
    },
    {
        "quotes":"A true friend sees the first tear, catches the second and stops the third."
    },
    {
        "quotes":"We carry our childhood with us!!"
    },
    {
        "quotes":"Childhood is the most beautiful of all lige's season!!"
    }
]
```

And these quotes want to displayed in a `<p class="copytxt">` element created by Javascript. Location in my javascript

```
  contents.innerHTML = paged.map(record => `<div class='latestatus'><p class='copytxt'>${record.quotes}</p><div> <button class="copystatus btn">Copy</button></div></div>`).join('');
  resultEl.append(contents);
};
```

If I run this code it shows all the quotes undefined. PLEASE if anyone have time run this above code and test it twice.

Comment: That's not valid JSON, it's missing `[` at the beginning. I guess this is a copying error since you're not getting a JSON parsing error.

Comment: Your json does not have a `status` key.  They all have only a `quotes` key.  Your map isn't going to match any property

Comment: `val.status` should be `val.quotes`.

Comment: Soory I forgot to add [

Comment: Yes thanks there was a mistake in map thanks @Barmar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove this part

```
  // finally go over the array and return new object with renamed key
  const results = data.map(val => ({quotes: val.status}));

  return results;
```

and return `data`, the field `status` does not exist in your json, and it's totally useless to remap the json just to have the same schema.

Answer (score 0):

I finally got the answer. The was a mistake in mapping. This was answered by @Barmar

```
const results = data.map(val => ({quotes: val.quotes}));
```